# PHP regex match not working with any variable except specific strings

Tags: php, regex, dom

I am trying to run a regex match on a DOM node and I cannot get it to work unless I print the node to the browser, copy the text and paste the exact text into the code. I'll explain it in code if that didn't make sense.

```
$text = $dom_node->nodeValue;
preg_match('my_regex', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches); //This returns an empty array
```

BUT! If I do this:

```
$text = $dom_node->nodeValue;
print_r($text);
```

Then copy-paste the output back into the code like this.

```
$text = 'copy paste text from before';
preg_match('my_regex', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches); //This returns the correct regex match
```

I get the right regex matches.

I've tried casting the $text variable as (string) too. Nothing seems to work with preg_match except for a specific string variable in quotes.

Comment: Can you edit your question and please provide the **real** strings and the regex?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code along with expected output

Comment: Check the "page source" , I am pretty sure html tags are present in the text which are not view able in browser .

Comment: Good call n01ze. Wasn't any tags but there were a bunch of line breaks in the source that were not visible in the browser. I did a str_replace to change them to spaces and everything worked out. Thanks!